# C - How do you call the first element in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, insertion-sort

I am trying to get a linked list to sort, then be able to display it.
The problem with my code is, I can display it before sorting, but after sorting, it won't display, it will crash. I think it has to do with the "top" variable, because through debugging, it doesn't contain anything. How can I call the first element in the linked list and use that to display them all? I am just really confused. 
Below is only the display and sort functions.

```
//Sort and display all employees
void displayAllEmps()
{
if(numEmps == 0)
{
    printf("No employees are hired.");
    fflush(stdout);
}
else
{
    char output[80];
    struct EMP* emp = top;

    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < numEmps; i++)
    {
        if (emp != NULL)
        {
            displayEmployee(emp, output);

            printf("%s", output);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        emp = emp -> next;
    }

}
}

//Sort function to call insertion sort function
void sortEmps()
{
temp = NULL;
struct EMP* next = top;

while(temp != NULL)
{
    next = top -> next;
    insert(temp);
    temp = next;
}

top = temp;
}

//Insertion sort function
void insert(struct EMP *emp)
{
prev = NULL;
current = temp;

while (current != NULL && current->id < emp->id)
{
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
}

if (prev == NULL)
{
    temp = emp;
}
else
{
    emp -> next = prev -> next;
    prev -> next = emp;
}
   }
```

Comment: Could you give us the actual error you're getting?

Comment: I think you need the emp = emp -> next; within the if (emp != NULL) {}, otherwise you are dereferencing a null pointer when emp is NULL.

Comment: It doesn't give an actual error. It just crashes in the displayAll function, anywhere "emp" is used. "top" doesn't give anything after the sort, so I believe "top" needs to be change, but idk what to.

Comment: What do you mean, it "just crashes"? As long as you're not crashing your entire system, you should see some sort of error message.

Comment: Also, just so you know, even without looking at your code, your description of your problem indicates that the real problem is in the "sort" function: if you are able to display your list just fine before sorting, and are unable to after sorting, then that should indicate to you that the *sorting* caused some sort of change to your list making it impossible to display.

Comment: You are asking the same question few times, -1

Comment: Sorting a linked list is sometimes done by putting the list in an array, sorting the array, then putting the sorted array back into a list -- no more problems with the initial element :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "sort" function is doing nothing except setting the head of your list to "NULL," so you don't actually have a list at all any more. The `while` loop is never entered, since `temp` is initially defined as `NULL`, so `temp != NULL` can't be true. You then set `top = temp;`, so now `top = NULL`.